# Why is the database not updated before a next Rule is launched?

Tags: 7, rules, database

I have two Rules (created with the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module) that are both launched when an article is flagged with the Flag *Approved*:

- **Rule 1**. Publish the flagged article with the action *Publish content*.
- **Rule 2**. Count the amount of published articles by the author of the flagged article. Display a message when this number is 5.

I'm using the following code in the condition of Rule 2:

```
return MYMODULE_count_articles($flagged_node->uid) == 5;
```

where my custom module contains the function

```
function MYMODULE_count_articles($uid) {
  $count = db_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM node WHERE uid=$uid AND status=1 AND type='article'")->fetchField();
  return $count;
}
```

The condition of Rule 2 is evaluated as `FALSE` when the 5th article is flagged with *Approved*, but evaluates as `TRUE` when a 6th article is flagged.

I suspect that this problem is caused because the database hasn't been updated yet when Rule 2 launches, because debugging the `$count` variable at the 5th flagging returns `4` instead of `5`. Also, executing the condition's code afterwards yields the correct value `5`.

Is this a know problem/phenomenon or a bug in the Rules module? Or is there an easy way to fix it (apart from changing the condition to `... == 4`, which is really dirty)?

Comment: Could it be cache? See [here](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/47970/5284). I'm not sure what Rule 1 is doing to publish the node, but in case if it's not using `node_save` then that link could contain the answer: Flush the flagged node's cache before getting the count. Maybe in the same function or by doing a separate function call...

Comment: @Beebee: I've clarified in my question that Rule 1 publishes nodes with a default action *Publish content*. Adding a second action that evaluates the PHP code from your link didn't solve the problem. Neither did the usage of that code in the condition of Rule 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [issue # 430274](https://www.drupal.org/node/430274), about an event which is a variation of your event here, and somehow explains that "after saving something" actually happens ... "before saving something" (which is not a bug, simply how the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module  works ...).

A possible compromise to avoid these kind of issues, is to transform what you're trying to do in your **Rule 2** in a Rules Component, so that your **Rule 1** "schedules the execution" (using the Rules Scheduler submodule) of that Rules Component. For example after only a few seconds or minutes later on (if your cron job runs frequent enough, otherwise it'll be next time cron runs). This compromise will ensure that, at the time the Rules Component is executed, the "Publish content" for sure completed, and your "number" will have been updated as expected.

Comment: I actually forgot about this question and only recently tried out your cool solution: I scheduled **Rule 2** 5 seconds after the current time. Since **Rule 2** should be executed as soon as possible, I would like to somehow force cron to run (it only runs once in an hour for the moment). Is there an easy way to do that or should I ask this in a new question?

Comment: @Jeroen : I am not aware of any Rules related solution to force cron to run. Though I'd be interested to learn/find out about that from anybody else. So maybe you should post a new question on that. Until some solution/answer for that comes up, you probably know about these 2 temporary work arounds: (a) run cron more frequently (every X mins) or (b) maybe "Elysia cron" may help somehow on this (not sure about that however).

Comment: Thanks Pierre. I asked http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/214769/how-to-force-a-cron-run-after-a-rules-component-is-scheduled and I will already have a look at Elysia cron, since that module might be what I am looking for.